# Renaming file name with shell script

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, scripting, filenames, rename

I have lots of file name like below;

```
KO.ADVT..HHE.D.2017.163.121959.SAC
KO.ADVT..HHN.D.2017.163.121957.SAC
KO.ADVT..HHZ.D.2017.163.121959.SAC
KO.ARMT..HHE.D.2017.163.121957.SAC
KO.ARMT..HHN.D.2017.163.121957.SAC
KO.ARMT..HHZ.D.2017.163.121956.SAC
KO.BGKT..HHE.D.2017.163.121958.SAC
KO.BGKT..HHN.D.2017.163.121959.SAC
KO.BGKT..HHZ.D.2017.163.121954.SAC
KO.BRGA..HNE.D.2017.163.121955.SAC
KO.BRGA..HNN.D.2017.163.121959.SAC
KO.BRGA..HNZ.D.2017.163.121959.SAC
KO.BUYA..HNE.D.2017.163.121954.SAC
KO.BUYA..HNN.D.2017.163.121955.SAC
KO.BUYA..HNZ.D.2017.163.121956.SAC
KO.CAVI..HHE.D.2017.163.121958.SAC
KO.CAVI..HHN.D.2017.163.121958.SAC
KO.CAVI..HHZ.D.2017.163.122001.SAC
KO.CRLT..HHE.D.2017.163.121958.SAC
KO.CRLT..HHN.D.2017.163.121959.SAC
KO.CRLT..HHZ.D.2017.163.121958.SAC
KO.CTYL..HHE.D.2017.163.122000.SAC
KO.CTYL..HHN.D.2017.163.121959.SAC
KO.CTYL..HHZ.D.2017.163.122004.SAC
KO.DST..HNE.D.2017.163.121959.SAC
KO.DST..HNN.D.2017.163.121957.SAC
KO.DST..HNZ.D.2017.163.121956.SAC
KO.EDRB..HHE.D.2017.163.121959.SAC
KO.EDRB..HHN.D.2017.163.121955.SAC
KO.EDRB..HHZ.D.2017.163.121958.SAC
```

and I want to change their name like this

```
ADVT.HHE.KO
ADVT.HHN.KO
ADVT.HHZ.KO
ARMT.HHE.KO
ARMT.HHN.KO
ARMT.HHZ.KO
BGKT.HHE.KO
BGKT.HHN.KO
BGKT.HHZ.KO
BRGA.HNE.KO
BRGA.HNN.KO
BRGA.HNZ.KO
BUYA.HNE.KO
BUYA.HNN.KO
BUYA.HNZ.KO
CAVI.HHE.KO
CAVI.HHN.KO
CAVI.HHZ.KO
CRLT.HHE.KO
CRLT.HHN.KO
CRLT.HHZ.KO
CTYL.HHE.KO
CTYL.HHN.KO
CTYL.HHZ.KO
DST.HNE.KO
DST.HNN.KO
DST.HNZ.KO
EDRB.HHE.KO
EDRB.HHN.KO
EDRB.HHZ.KO
```

I used this code

```
 for file in *.SAC
    do
        newfilename="${file:3:6}${file:7:9}"
    echo mv $file $newfilename
    done
```

but the result like this;

```
ADVT....HHE.D.2
ADVT....HHN.D.2
ADVT....HHZ.D.2
DST..H.HNE.D.20
DST..H.HNN.D.20
DST..H.HNZ.D.20
.... so on.
```

How can I get new files names with my code ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
for f in *SAC; do
    echo mv "$f" "$(awk -F. -v OFS=. '{print $2, $4, $1}' <<< "$f")"
done
```

Remove `echo` statement if the output looks good

Comment: Quenoti this is also works, thank you so much !!!

Comment: This is less elegant than perl's one, up2u (IMO)

Comment: I have never used perl but I wonder about it. Is there any suggestion how can I learn perl coding ?

Comment: Sure, find an assignment of treating text/xml/JSON... Any data, and start learning. Perl is amazing when you need to treat data. The regex engine is the best/most advanced one of the high level languages out there. I'm a fan of perl one-liners, you can do many things with just one line of condensed line.

Comment: thank you so much @Gilles Quenot again !

Answer (score 2):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) `rename`:

```
rename -n 's/^(.*?)\.(.*?)\.\.(.*?)\..*/$2.$3.$1/' *SAC
```

Remove `-n` switch if the output looks good.

`.*?` is like `.*` but *not greedy*

Comment: @Gilles Quenot it works like a charm :) thanks a lot  !!!