# Taking a specific part of the file name with shell script and put into loop

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, scripting, filenames

Let me explain, .SAC files are type of seismograms which SAC ( Seismic Analysis Code ) program use and the other files which contains *HH are response files. I want to remove insturment response which can be done by SAC. the code 1633 1703 etc station codes which has three component. North-south (N), east-west (E) and vertical (Z). My code makes one station at once. So I just want to make a match with SAC filenames which contains response files first 4 characters and loop for them.

I have lots of file names like this for SAC;

```
TK.1633..HNE.D.2017.163.122458.SAC
TK.1633..HNN.D.2017.163.122457.SAC
TK.1633..HNZ.D.2017.163.122458.SAC
TK.1703..HNE.D.2017.163.122457.SAC
TK.1703..HNN.D.2017.163.122456.SAC
TK.1703..HNZ.D.2017.163.122458.SAC
TK.3405..HNE.D.2017.163.122456.SAC
TK.3405..HNN.D.2017.163.122457.SAC
TK.3405..HNZ.D.2017.163.122457.SAC
TK.3406..HNE.D.2017.163.122457.SAC
TK.3406..HNN.D.2017.163.122458.SAC
TK.3406..HNZ.D.2017.163.122457.SAC
```

and also like this;

```
1633.HHE
1633.HHN
1633.HHZ
1703.HHE
1703.HHN
1703.HHZ
3405.HHE
3405.HHN
3405.HHZ
3406.HHE
3406.HHN
3406.HHZ
```

I write this code

```
for file in *TK.1633*HNE*
do 
for response in 1633_HHE
do 
sac << END
r $file
rmean
rtrend
transfer from polezero subtype $response to none 
w ${file}_noresp
q
END
done
done

for file in *TK.1633*HNN*
do 
for response in 1633.HHN
do 
sac << END
r $file
rmean
rtrend
transfer from polezero subtype $response to none 
w ${file}_noresp
q
END
done
done

for file in *TK.1633*HNZ*
do 
for response in 1633.HHZ
do 
sac << END
r $file
rmean
rtrend
transfer from polezero subtype $response to none 
w ${file}_noresp
q
END
done
done
```

I want to take a for example TK.1633..HNE.D.2017.163.122458.SAC "1633" part and make a match with 1633.HHE file in shell script and make this process for all files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me it's very unclear what you're trying to do. Why you have HNZ and HHZ mixed? Could explain the relevance of the `rename` tag? And could you possibly accept the answer on your [other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593421/236063)?

Comment: Please, indent your code

Comment: fwiw, `sac` here is probably Seismic Analysis Code in the realm of geophysics.

Comment: @pLumo
Sorry for being unclear, you are right about it. Let me explain, *.SAC files are type of seismograms which SAC ( Seismic Analysis Code ) program uses (thanks for explaining @A.B.) and the other files which contains *HH* are response files. I want to remove insturment response which can be done by SAC. the code *1633* *1703* etc station codes which has three component. North-south (N), east-west (E) and vertical (Z). My code makes one station at once. So I just want to make a match with SAC filenames which contains response files first 4 characters and loop for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `bash`:

```bsh
for name in TK.*.SAC; do
        resp=${name#TK.}        # remove initial TK.
        resp=${resp%.D.*}       # remove all from .D. onwards

        resp=${resp/../.}       # change .. into .
        resp=${resp/N/H}        # change first N into H

        if [[ ! -f $resp ]]; then
                printf 'Missing response file "%s" for "%s"\n' "$resp" "$name" >&2
                continue
        fi

        sac <<-END_SAC
                r $name
                rmean
                rtrend
                transfer from polezero subtype $resp to none
                w ${name}_noresp
                q
        END_SAC
done
```

This loops over all your `TK.*.SAC` files and computes the name of the corresponding response file.  If ith response file is missing for a SAC file, like the three `3419.HH?` files in your example list, a message will be outputted and `sac` will not be executed.

If `$resp` exists, `sac` is executed with the same script that you show.

Note the use of literal tabs to indent the here-document and its terminating `END_SAC` delimiter here. I'm using `<<-END_SAC` and it's the `-` that tells the shell to strip the initial tabs from the contents of the here-document before feeding it into `sac`.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question and also for your answer @Kusalananda♦, I tried your code but it doesn't work. 
It gives line 21: warning: here-document at line 13 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `END')
./deneme.sh: line 22: syntax error: unexpected end of file error.

Comment: @curious That's because you haven't indented the here-document and the `END_SAC` delimiter using tab characters but spaces. If you want to use spaces for indentation, then make sure that `END_SAC` is not indented at all.

Comment: you have already warned me, how careless I am.... It works, I cry from happiness, thank you for million times @Kusalananda♦ !!!

Answer (score 0):

This could help i think :

```
$ for file in *.SAC
do
HHfile=$(echo $file | sed -e 's/TK.\([0-9]\+\)\.\.HN\(.\)\.D.*/\1\.HH\2/')
echo $HHfile
#Do whatever you want
done
```